# How can I create lazy properties in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Suppose I have a class with three fields, `a`, `b` and `sum`. The third one should always equal to the sum of `a` and `b`.

In pure Python, this would have been implemented simply as:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def sum(self):
        return self.a + self.b
```

However in Kivy, we are encouraged to use the Property descriptors of the framework. Before including `sum`, the class would be:

```
class MyClass(Widget):
    a = NumericProperty()
    b = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, a, b, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

However, how should I implement the `sum` property? I can use a good ol' `@property`. But shouldn't I instead use some sort of Kivy `Property` object?

What would be the best practice in Kivy to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked into what NumericProperty actually does? It's possible you can make the sum property as normal and also do `sum = NumericProperty`

Comment: If you don't want sum to evaluate until you access it, using a normal python property is fine. You can use a NumericProperty with a kv rule `sum: self.a + self.b` if you want it to be reevaluated every time self.a or self.b changes, and/or if you want to bind to `sum` with Kivy's event system.

Answer (score 1):

In general, properties are here to help you display contents of class fields on widgets. You can use them, or not.

You can use the `@property`, and create `update_sum(..)` method in some widget to rewrite a new sum to a label, on a button press.

Or you can do this automatically by creating an [alias property](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.AliasProperty), updating the label each time the sum changes, so you don't have to click any buttons to update it.

*main.py*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, AliasProperty


class RootBox(BoxLayout):

    a = NumericProperty()
    b = NumericProperty()

    def get_sum(self):
        return float(self.a + self.b)

    def set_sum(self, value):
        self.sum = value

    sum = AliasProperty(get_sum, set_sum, bind=['a', 'b'])

    def on_sum(self, obj, value):
        self.ids.sum_label.text = str(value)


class Test(App):
    pass


Test().run()
```

*test.kv*:

```
RootBox:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        id: sum_label

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        TextInput:
            on_text: root.a = float(self.text) if self.text else 0
        TextInput:
            on_text: root.b = float(self.text) if self.text else 0
```

Comment: AliasProperty looks good. I can't fjgure out what the `bind` parameter is for. Why is it necessary after setting the setter and the getter?

Comment: @AvivCohn It binds the setters of properties `a` and `b`. Whenever these single properties change, it will affect the sum, executing `on_sum` method. There is a link to docs in my answer.